# How to find Window is closed or not in angular

Tags: angular

Hey i am using angular 5 in my project. For some click i am opening some URL in another tab. I want to do some update on close of the newly opened tab.Below is the code i tried but i am not able to get any alert message.Where i am going wrong?

```
commentAction(action: string, id: number) {
            var url ='someurl';
            var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
            win.focus();
            var timer = setInterval(function() {   
                alert('timer is running');
                if(win.closed) {  
                    clearInterval(timer);  
                    alert('doing some update');  
                }  
            }, 1000); 
        }
```

Comment: I can only imagine you blocked the page from showing anymore alerts

Comment: How i am doing that sir?

Comment: remove timer is running alert, it worked for me. and try to print win object, whether you are getting anything in win object.

Comment: working. But on win closed i want to call method of Angular service. How to do that ?

Comment: @JEng you need to use the arrow function notation `() => {}` and not `function() {}`

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong approach you are using to detect if new window is closed as its checking every 1000 seconds. Also you should do clearInterval after alert.

**In Newly Opened window have this :-**

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    window.parent.postMessage('closed');
}
```

**In Existing Component**

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
onMessage(event) {
  if(event ==='closed') {
    alert('doing some update');
  }
}
```

Comment: newly opened window is link off external API where i don't have code control.

Comment: in your own code try to print win, what does it give you? because i ran your code in browser console and it was working. I just removed timer is running alert.